# How to auto-run React-Native App on device starup

Tags: react-native

How to start a react-native app on device startup on Android. I have an Android app developed on react-native and if the app is running and user restarts his device, I wish to auto start my app.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `react-native-autostart` npm package.

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new .java file named BootReceiver.java:

```
 package com.packageName;

 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
  myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(myIntent);
}
}
```

then I edited the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name="com.packageName.BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter >
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Comment: Make sure you put those <receiver> codes in side <Application> otherwise you will have hard time to debug and find an error.